# How to free CGRect, CGPoint types in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

I am using `CGRect`, `CGPoint` types in my project several times. I can nill the swift objects but i cant set nil values to `C` types. How can i free `CGRect` and `CGPoint` from swift?

Comment: You don't need to, they're not classes.

Comment: You can't nil objects if they're not declared as optional. You can nil-ify only optionals (either objects or value types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGrect`, `CGPoint` etc are so called *value types*.  You do not need to worry about releasing them really.  You can consider value-type variables to be allocated on stack and therefore being thrown away the moment you leave the scope of a method.

There is a short [article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10) at the swift blog that explains the difference between value types and reference types.

[Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48) applies to reference types *only*.  There you can consider objects to be allocated on heap.